# Reference to standard Android strings in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, string

In my Java code, I can easily access standard Android strings like "save", "ok", "cancel", etcetera. In an activity, I can do this as follows:
`getString(android.R.string.cancel)`

I would like to access these strings from inside an XML file. I've tried things like `android:text="@android:string/cancel`, but this doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to use those strings in XML?

Comment: "this doesn't seem to work" -- hmmm... I would expect that to work. What are your specific symptoms?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Android studio says `Cannot resolve symbol`. It autocompletes the `android:` part, but when writing the `string/` part, it doesn't show any tooltip anymore.

Comment: use `@string/cancel`

Comment: @Marcel50506 That's a mystery. Works well for me too. Try a clean build. Also make sure you have no other errors in the xml.

Comment: Somehow I can't reproduce the problem anymore today. Must have been a clean-build situation, although I've tried that yesterday. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem. With Android Studio 2.2.2, I just created a new project from the new-project wizard, choosing "Empty Activity" as the template and unchecking the appcompat option. Then, in `activity_main.xml`, I changed the `TextView` to refer to your desired string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.commonsware.myapplication.MainActivity">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@android:string/cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This builds cleanly and runs on Android 7.1.

Since that string has been in the SDK since API Level 1, I would not anticipate any problems in using it.

Answer (score 0):

try android:text="@string/cancel"